# Installing QGIS QGIS 2.18.13-1 for Mac 10.11.6 El Cap?

Tags: installation, qgis-2, mac

When opening Qgis I get this in the python warning and the following under processing. Any help would be great.

2017-10-27T20:45:03 2   Problem with OTB installation: installed OTB version (5.2.1) is not supported
2017-10-27T20:45:03 2   Problem with SAGA installation: unsupported SAGA version found.

2017-10-27T20:44:52 1   warning:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py:186: ImportWarning: Not importing directory '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/mpl_toolkits': missing **init**.py
              file, filename, etc = imp.find_module(subname, path)

```
        traceback:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 333, in startPlugin
            plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/MetaSearch/__init__.py", line 29, in classFactory
            from MetaSearch.plugin import MetaSearchPlugin
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/MetaSearch/plugin.py", line 33, in <module>
            from MetaSearch.dialogs.maindialog import MetaSearchDialog
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/MetaSearch/dialogs/maindialog.py", line 43, in <module>
            from owslib.csw import CatalogueServiceWeb
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/owslib/csw.py", line 27, in <module>
            from owslib.util import OrderedDict
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/owslib/util.py", line 15, in <module>
            import pytz
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/pytz/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
            from pkg_resources import resource_stream
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2813, in <module>
            add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
          File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in subscribe
            callback(dist)
          File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2813, in <lambda>
            add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
          File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2346, in activate
            list(map(declare_namespace, self._get_metadata('namespace_packages.txt')))
          File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1942, in declare_namespace
            _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
          File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1899, in _handle_ns
            loader = importer.find_module(packageName)
```

2017-10-27T20:44:53 1   warning:/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7/pyspatialite/dbapi2.py:81: DeprecationWarning: Converters and adapters are deprecated. Please use only supported SQLite types. Any type mapping should happen in layer above this module.
              register_adapter(datetime.date, adapt_date)

```
        traceback:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 298, in loadPlugin
            __import__(packageName)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
            from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 31, in <module>
            from processing.core.Processing import Processing
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 42, in <module>
            from processing.script.ScriptUtils import ScriptUtils
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptUtils.py", line 30, in <module>
            from processing.script.ScriptAlgorithm import ScriptAlgorithm
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptAlgorithm.py", line 33, in <module>
            from processing.core.GeoAlgorithm import GeoAlgorithm
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/GeoAlgorithm.py", line 41, in <module>
            from processing.core.parameters import ParameterRaster, ParameterVector, ParameterMultipleInput, ParameterTable, Parameter
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/parameters.py", line 32, in <module>
            from processing.tools.vector import resolveFieldIndex
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/vector.py", line 47, in <module>
            from processing.tools import dataobjects, spatialite, postgis
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/spatialite.py", line 29, in <module>
            from pyspatialite import dbapi2 as sqlite
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7/pyspatialite/dbapi2.py", line 86, in <module>
            register_adapters_and_converters()
```

2017-10-27T20:44:53 1   warning:/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7/pyspatialite/dbapi2.py:82: DeprecationWarning: Converters and adapters are deprecated. Please use only supported SQLite types. Any type mapping should happen in layer above this module.
              register_adapter(datetime.datetime, adapt_datetime)

```
        traceback:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 298, in loadPlugin
            __import__(packageName)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
            from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 31, in <module>
            from processing.core.Processing import Processing
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 42, in <module>
            from processing.script.ScriptUtils import ScriptUtils
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptUtils.py", line 30, in <module>
            from processing.script.ScriptAlgorithm import ScriptAlgorithm
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptAlgorithm.py", line 33, in <module>
            from processing.core.GeoAlgorithm import GeoAlgorithm
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/GeoAlgorithm.py", line 41, in <module>
            from processing.core.parameters import ParameterRaster, ParameterVector, ParameterMultipleInput, ParameterTable, Parameter
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/parameters.py", line 32, in <module>
            from processing.tools.vector import resolveFieldIndex
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/vector.py", line 47, in <module>
            from processing.tools import dataobjects, spatialite, postgis
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/spatialite.py", line 29, in <module>
            from pyspatialite import dbapi2 as sqlite
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7/pyspatialite/dbapi2.py", line 86, in <module>
            register_adapters_and_converters()
```

2017-10-27T20:44:53 1   warning:/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7/pyspatialite/dbapi2.py:83: DeprecationWarning: Converters and adapters are deprecated. Please use only supported SQLite types. Any type mapping should happen in layer above this module.
              register_converter("date", convert_date)

```
        traceback:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 298, in loadPlugin
            __import__(packageName)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
            from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 31, in <module>
            from processing.core.Processing import Processing
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 42, in <module>
            from processing.script.ScriptUtils import ScriptUtils
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptUtils.py", line 30, in <module>
            from processing.script.ScriptAlgorithm import ScriptAlgorithm
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptAlgorithm.py", line 33, in <module>
            from processing.core.GeoAlgorithm import GeoAlgorithm
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/GeoAlgorithm.py", line 41, in <module>
            from processing.core.parameters import ParameterRaster, ParameterVector, ParameterMultipleInput, ParameterTable, Parameter
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/parameters.py", line 32, in <module>
            from processing.tools.vector import resolveFieldIndex
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/vector.py", line 47, in <module>
            from processing.tools import dataobjects, spatialite, postgis
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/spatialite.py", line 29, in <module>
            from pyspatialite import dbapi2 as sqlite
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7/pyspatialite/dbapi2.py", line 86, in <module>
            register_adapters_and_converters()
```

2017-10-27T20:44:53 1   warning:/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7/pyspatialite/dbapi2.py:84: DeprecationWarning: Converters and adapters are deprecated. Please use only supported SQLite types. Any type mapping should happen in layer above this module.
              register_converter("timestamp", convert_timestamp)

```
        traceback:  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 298, in loadPlugin
            __import__(packageName)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
            from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 31, in <module>
            from processing.core.Processing import Processing
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 42, in <module>
            from processing.script.ScriptUtils import ScriptUtils
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptUtils.py", line 30, in <module>
            from processing.script.ScriptAlgorithm import ScriptAlgorithm
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptAlgorithm.py", line 33, in <module>
            from processing.core.GeoAlgorithm import GeoAlgorithm
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/GeoAlgorithm.py", line 41, in <module>
            from processing.core.parameters import ParameterRaster, ParameterVector, ParameterMultipleInput, ParameterTable, Parameter
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/parameters.py", line 32, in <module>
            from processing.tools.vector import resolveFieldIndex
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/vector.py", line 47, in <module>
            from processing.tools import dataobjects, spatialite, postgis
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/spatialite.py", line 29, in <module>
            from pyspatialite import dbapi2 as sqlite
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
            mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7/pyspatialite/dbapi2.py", line 86, in <module>
            register_adapters_and_converters()
```

Comment: Homebrew or kingchaos version? It’s unclear the information about installation

Comment: I'm using the kingchaos version

Answer (score 1):

1) Try first to deactivate OTB and SAGA providers on the processing settings.

2) Install the [Kyng Chaos Python module Matplotlib](http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/python/matplotlib-1.4.3-1.dmg). It gets installed into the  `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override` directory and a `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override.pth` file). If you use the Kyng Chaos version, **you absolutely need it**.

[image]

In the Python shell or the Python console of QGIS

```
import mpl_toolkits
mpl_toolkits.__file__
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override/mpl_toolkits/__init__.pyc
```

and not `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/mpl_toolkits`'

3) warning:/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7/pyspatialite/dbapi2.py:83: DeprecationWarning

It is only a [Warning: deprecation warning](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.DeprecationWarning). If you really want to  ignore them (lines  81 to 84), you can use the correction proposed in [bugs.python.org](https://bugs.python.org/review/26651/diff/16846/Lib/sqlite3/dbapi2.py)

Replace in the file /Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7/pyspatialite/dbapi2.py, lines  81 to 84

```
def register_adapters_and_converters():
    .....
    register_adapter(datetime.date, adapt_date)
    register_adapter(datetime.datetime, adapt_datetime)
    register_converter("date", convert_date)
register_adapters_and_converters()
```

by

```
import warnings
.....
def register_adapters_and_converters():
    .....
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
       warnings.simplefilter('ignore', DeprecationWarning)
       register_adapter(datetime.date, adapt_date)
       register_adapter(datetime.datetime, adapt_datetime)
       register_converter("date", convert_date)
register_adapters_and_converters()
```